# SQL - insert multiple line without double

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to insert multiple lines into a database, but I inserted only one line or insert with missing line

My SQL table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` 
(
    `ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `time` datetime NOT NULL,
    `nb_osuser` int NOT NULL,
    `osuser_name` nvarchar(100)NOT NULL,
    `program` nvarchar(100)NOT NULL,
    `last_line` nvarchar(100)NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    UNIQUE KEY (`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Insert query:

```
#Connect to the database.
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=database;host=IP",
"hostname", 'password',
{'RaiseError' => 1});

while (my ($user, $ref) = each %counts) {
  while (my ($program, $count) = each %$ref) {
    #print "$count OSUSER with session $user and with program $program\n";
    print "time = $time, count = $count, user = $user, program = $program, last_line = $last_line\n";

    $request ="'$time', '$count', '$user', '$program', $last_line";

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("REPLACE `test` (time, nb, os_name, program, last_line) VALUES($request);")
  }
}
```

Data in my table:

```
       ID  USER                      TERMINAL        SERVICE                    
---------- ------------------------- --------------- -------------------------  
         1 toto                      titi            roro          
         2 toto                      titi            roro          
         4 gigi                      gege            fefe
```

I want:

```
+----+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
| ID | time                | nb        | os_name     | program        | last_line |
+----+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
| 15  | 2019-01-04 14:00:00|        33 | titi        | roro           | 109       |
| 16  | 2019-01-04 14:00:00|        9  | gege        | fefe           | 109       |
```

Thanks for any information

Comment: It's really hard to understand what this question is about; what's going wrong? You're only getting one line inserted despite the loop running multiple times?

Comment: replace works with unique keys. The only unique keys are ID and time. You don't pass ID to the replace statement at all, so that won't be used. The time could be used, but apparently it's different, since it's not used to replace the existing row. You did share 'my log', but the log doesn't show the time, which is a highly relevant piece of information. Maybe you can log the time too, and see if the problem is there.

Comment: time is always the same

Comment: What does  "UNIQUE KEY (`time`)"  do for you?